# Renaming and cleaning up filenames of TV shows to be S01E01.mp4 etc

Tags: bash, scripting, rename, mv

If I have some TV Shows that are named badly and I need to clean them up

```
$ ls
Some_Series.1_Episode.1.mp4  'Some Series01.Episode02.mp4' SomeSeries1Episode03.mp4
```

I need to batch rename them to become

```
$ ls
S01E01.mp4  S01E02.mp4  S01E03.mp4
```

I have used the following script and it works but only when the original filenames contain Series and Episode numbers 01 02 03 and not 1 2 3

```
#!/bin/bash
# rename tv show filenames to be kodi friendly
cd /mnt/2tb_hd/con/
if [ $? == 1 ]; then 
    exit
fi
for filename in *; do
        if [[ "$filename" =~(\**).*(.*[0-9][0-9]).*([0-9][0-9]).*(\....)$ ]]; then
            result=$(echo mv \"$filename\" S${BASH_REMATCH[2]}E${BASH_REMATCH[3]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}\") 

                if [[ $? == 0 ]] ; then 
                    mv "$filename" "S${BASH_REMATCH[2]}E${BASH_REMATCH[3]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
                fi
            fi
        done
        exit
```

I need to make this code either change any 1 2 3 4 5 etc in the filenames to have a 0 padding before running the 2nd renaming loop or just alter the code I already have to change either 01 or 1 regardless of the 0 padding.

Sorry if this seems really obvious but I am new to bash so please forgive me.

---

I have updated the script and now I have issues with episode 8 and 9. I get the following error

```
line 10: printf: 08: invalid octal number
```

So episode 8 and 9 are missing but there is one extra file S02E00.mkv for each series with over 7 episodes.

The adapted script

```
#!/bin/bash
# rename tv show files to kodi friendly format S01E01 etc
cd /mnt/2tb_hd/Adults/TV_Shows/Breaking\ Bad/
if [ $? == 1 ]; then 
    exit
fi
reg='^([^0-9]*)([0-9][0-9]*)[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9]*).*(\....)$'
for filename in *.*; do
      if [[ $filename =~ $reg ]]; then
              printf -v newname 'S%02dE%02d%s' "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
                  mv "$filename" "$newname"
                fi
            done
        exit
```

See http://pastebin.com/2XRH85ua for the full outcome of the test run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `printf`, with a format string that specifies field width and zero-padding for the integers e.g.

```
printf -v newname 'S%02dE%02d%s' "$((10#${BASH_REMATCH[2]}))" "$((10#${BASH_REMATCH[3]}))" "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
```

**Note the use of `$((10#${BASH_REMATCH[n]}))` to force decimal evaluation in cases like `09`**

Testing (I modified your regular expression slightly BTW):

```
reg='^([^0-9]*)([0-9][0-9]*)[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9]*)(\....)$'
for filename in *.mp4; do
  if [[ $filename =~ $reg ]]; then
    printf -v newname 'S%02dE%02d%s' "$((10#${BASH_REMATCH[2]}))" "$((10#${BASH_REMATCH[3]}))" "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    echo mv "$filename" "$newname"
  fi
done
mv Some Series01.Episode02.mp4 S01E02.mp4
mv SomeSeries1Episode03.mp4 S01E03.mp4
mv Some_Series.1_Episode.1.mp4 S01E01.mp4
```

Possibly more robust would be to use the regex *only* to match the first two sequences of digits, and use shell parameter substitution to handle the extension:

```
reg='([0-9][0-9]*)[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9]*)'
for filename in *.mp4 *.mkv; do
  name="${filename%.*}"
  ext="${filename##*.}"
  if [[ $name =~ $reg ]]; then
    printf -v newname 'S%02dE%02d.%s' "$((10#${BASH_REMATCH[1]}))" "$((10#${BASH_REMATCH[2]}))" "${ext}"
    echo mv "$filename" "$newname"
  fi
done
mv Some Series01.Episode02.mp4 S01E02.mp4
mv SomeSeries09Episode10.mp4 S09E10.mp4
mv SomeSeries1Episode03.mp4 S01E03.mp4
mv Some_Series.1_Episode.1.mp4 S01E01.mp4
mv Breaking.Bad.S01E01.576p.BluRay.DD5.1.x264-HiSD.mkv S01E01.mkv
```

---

Alternatively, if your system has the perl-based `rename` / `prename` command, you could so something like

```
prename -vn -- 's/.*(\d+).*(\d+)/sprintf "S%02dE%02d.mp4", $1, $2/e' *.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be working perfectly now. I'm not sure why you put the echo line in. I removed the echo and just have mv "$filename" "$newname" and it seems to be renaming files containing whitespaces and periods. I still need to fully test it on batches of files but time will tell.  Thanks for your help

Comment: It doesn't work on filenames like this 'Breaking.Bad.S01E01.576p.BluRay.DD5.1.x264-HiSD.mkv' could it be the periods or extra numbers in the filename? The problem is that files are always named really badly in an inconsistent way. I have changed the mp4 for mkv in the script.

Comment: @s7ntax try changing the regex to `reg='^([^0-9]*)([0-9][0-9]*)[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9]*).*(\....)$'` to match (and discard) an extra sequence of arbitrary characters between the second sequence of digits and the extension.

Comment: @s7ntax I've added a variant that I think may be more robust

Comment: OK - just a note, you may want to add the `-n` or `--no-clobber` flag to your `mv` in case there are names that conflict once they are stripped of the other strings

Comment: Yes I will do, I think that it has named episode 08 as 00 then clobbered it with episode 09 giving it the same filename. Any reason why 8 and 9 would not process the same. It reported line 10: printf: 08: invalid octal number on processing many files and the same for 9. See edited post above.

Comment: @s7ntax Doh! yes there is - sorry for not catching that - bash will treat numbers with leading zeros as octal by default. Let me think the best way to handle that.

Comment: @s7ntax please see edited version - hopefully you can now see why use of shell tools is not always recommended for text processing, it can get complicated pretty quickly ;)

Comment: Yes it certainly does. This is working fine now. Just as long as I don't come across any filenames that have numbers before the Season or Episode number it should work fine for my purposes and will save me a lot of typing for sure. Thank you for taking time to help a bash noob out with this. I have a lot to learn. :)